# Disadvantages for large session timeout values?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, authentication, session-timeout, application-pool

I have my `SessionState` timeout set at two hours. What disadvantages exist for having large session timeout values? I included the authentication timeout value for clarity.

```
<sessionState timeout="120" />
...
<forms name="login" timeout="240" />
```

I've also read that the application pool recycling plays a roll in timeouts<sup>1</sup>. Are there any other timeout values or processes that should be evaluated when configuring a system (ideally to minimize user impact)?

<sup>1</sup> https://stackoverflow.com/a/3916997/1085891

**-- Edit 1 --**

I ask because increasing the session state size was a solution implemented to deal with timeout issues on a system I work on. I've read that longer session states hold on to memory longer so that would be one disadvantage.

Answer (score 0):

It matters if you store anything in the session object or not. If not, then IIS will just keep the session id as it can recreate the session object from that, and having a long session timeout is less expensive.

Comment: This question was asked with the assumption that data would be stored in the session. Updated my question for clarification. You answer doesn't provide much insight.