# Web.Config session timeout not set, vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session-timeout

I have read about a million posts online regarding session timeout in config file and I am near tears.  I have the following code in my config file.  I have set the timeout to 1 minute as a test.  The session does indeed end within 1 minutee however, if I set to 120 (2 hours) which is what i want, the session end after the default time of 20 minutes i believe.  Can anyone offer some help.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="1" >
</sessionState> 
<compilation debug="true"/>
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx"
    loginUrl="~/Default.aspx"
    name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"
    slidingExpiration="true"
    timeout="1" />
</authentication> 
<customErrors mode="Off" />
 </system.web>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: A similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915810/timeout-and-session-timeout-issue?rq=1. You might want to check it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If an app pool is idle for 20 minutes it will recycle by default, see image below.

See this [Microsoft post](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) about changing the default.

[image: Advanced App pool settings]

**UPDATE**
If you do not have access to the *IIS Application Pool Settings* you can try the adding the following to your `web.config` however the recommended approach is via `IIS`

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="120" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry if I sound stupid (i'm a newby-ish) If this is the case the session is dependant on the users own windows os settings?

Comment: That is not possible, this is a setting in the IIS app pool. if you do not have access to the webserver try the session state web.config setting... see updated answer

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help.  I now understand the idle timeout setting for a browser session is set in the IIS pool on the server which the users terminal is operating, therefore I have decided to bypass the session for the purposes of my log in.

Comment: Sorry Ashley that requires 15 reputation apparently.